# howto find_by ownkey the exact entry in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, findby

we have an show-action which should find by the own_key the right entry. The own_key is generated as UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create().to_s.
The following question is now here.

```
class ListController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json
  def show
    @list = List.find_by_own_key(params[:own_key])
    respond_with(@list)
  end
end
```

the routes are here so generates

```
resources :lists
match '/:id' => 'list#show'
```

why did we get also an entry back if we only type one simple letter after the /?
The own_key look so `f6d47c20-a276-11e1-b127-68a3c454c2b4`. So if we type an /lists/f i get the entry with an f own_key. how can we manage that we only get the entry with the own_key?
Could it run by an contraint?

thanks for the help if anone can help us?

Marcus

Comment: So is there an entry whose key is exactly 'f' or not?

Comment: No the key are never only one letter, they were always generated by UUID tool. thats our problem that the filtering is not correct

Comment: That doesn't sound like it should happen. Worth am checking what SQL gets executed.

Comment: That is the output from the development.log
`Started GET "/lists/f6d47c20-a276-11e1-b127-68a3c454c2b4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-20 20:17:08 +0200
Processing by ListsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"f6d47c20-a276-11e1-b127-68a3c454c2b4"}
  List Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."admin_key" IS NULL LIMIT 1[0m
  Rendered lists/show.html`

Comment: Now i get an other problem. i always get the same entry... with this show-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your routes, `params[:id]` will contain the I'd to search for, however you're using `params[:own_key]` which will be nil. Instead of searching for the record with the specified value of own_key your code will always fetch the row with a null own_key.

Change your code to use params[:id] and you should be ok

Answer (score 0):

U can use constrainsts for route or check params[:own_key] in controller

`:constraints => {:own_key=> /regexp pattern for uuid/}`